# Should TLS clients put a limit on certificate chain depth?

Tags: tls, certificates, x.509

Specifcally, when [configuring nginx to validate proxy target SSL certificates](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/) (which it mystifyingly does not do by default), a maximum cert chain depth must be specified in the `proxy_ssl_verify_depth` option. If I am writing a configuration to be used in environments in which I do not control how deep the cert chain may be, is there a reason for this to have any particular limit, or should it just be a high number? I haven't encountered any other TLS client that even exposes this as configurable, let alone has the default value of 1 (no intermediate CAs) that nginx does. So I'm thinking it should just be a high number to avoid running into it unnecessarily, but not sure if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is DoS prevention: building the chain might be an exponential algorithm with backoff, so with the [openssl default of 100](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/crypto/x509/x509_vpm.c#L482) a malicious backend might cause denial of service in nginx. I would use 10. In practice, 4 should be enough.